# `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6)

Tags: linux, debian, libraries, gcc

For a program, I am getting

```
GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

on a Debian AMD64 machine. I am guessing the most likely issue is that the program is linked against this library but the necessary object files are missing on my system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `build-essential`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```